# Google will discontinue support for sign-ins to Google accounts from embedded browser frameworks

Tags: webview, google-oauth, google-contacts-api, embedded-browser, google-sso

I work for a company that has application for 4 platforms (Android, IOS, windows, and web) and before a couple of days we get this message:
**"Google will discontinue support for sign-ins to Google accounts from embedded browser frameworks, starting January 4, 2021"**

In **Android** and **iOS** app we use the Google SDK to login and in the **web** and in the **windows** app we loaded the google sso throw a webview.
I have 2 questions:

1. I think that the problem is on the windows app, does anyone know if Google means to a webview also as **"embedded browser frameworks"**?
2. What exactly are the **embedded browser frameworks**? it is loading the sso on chrome, explorer, etc.?

I tried to understand from this post: [Google Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html) but without success

Comment: Did you run the test for compatibility? What was the result?

Comment: Hi, I run the test and found no differences between the login with header and without it. what did I need to see in the test?

Comment: hey @gilcohen, we received the same email – we have iOS, Android and Web apps. Why do you think it relates to your Windows app?
In iOS and Android, we do see that it uses embedded browser – isn’t it the same for you? Although we also uses the latest SDKs

Comment: Hi, @ofer2980 in the android and in iOS we use google API and not browser like in the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating. in UWP we use in webview this is why I think the mail according to the windows app

Comment: Got you, I understand. Thanks!!

Comment: By "Google API" you mean the Google SDKs to sign in? iOS and Android

Comment: Yes yes of course, my bad